# ExpressionListInit how to create list

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I am trying to hydrate an array using the Linq.Expression namespace as this will be built into an IQueryable projection helper.

So far, I have managed to get the constructor for the list, identify its type, and now I am stuck with how to build an expression that will iterate over the source list and and return a new item for this new array to be initialised with.

Expression.Loop seems to be my best bet, but I can't figure out how to make it loop over the source array and give me back my converted items?

Anyone got any pointers of where I can start?

Si

Comment: A piece of code (what you already did) might help you to get answers ;-)

Comment: Struggling to get anything that works at the moment, I am not sure how I would take a list and pass it through to an expression that uses memberinit to bind the individual properties of it.